# View Page source of web page on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a app on which I want to provide a facility to "VIEW SOURCE" of any webpage on button click.User will only enter URL and will get source of that page.I also want to show contents,stylesheets,images of that webpage .I want to get all these and show in my asp.net pages according to my formats.Please Help....

Comment: Can you please clarify what you have problem with: how to show content of the file on a page, how to properly encode a text when displaying on a page, how to format arbitrary text according to my format, something else?

Answer (score 2):

you can use **`web client`** in asp.net

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
const string strUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com/"; 
byte[] reqHTML; 
reqHTML = webClient.DownloadData(strUrl); 
UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding(); 
lblWebpage.Text = objUTF8.GetString(reqHTML); 

}
```

here you can pass your page url in `strUrl` ,  [read more](http://forums.asp.net/p/1058879/1515859.aspx) 
if you want to use javascript then  [read this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=76)

Comment: +1 to this and @sajanyamaha answers... After re-reading the question couple times getting remote data is probably the only thing OP missing. Parsing HTML with HtmlAgilityPack for links to CSS should not be a problem.

Comment: I get the yahoo page as it is in original website.But I have designed my separate aspx pages.Now I want to use images,menu bar,some content in my aspx pages.My problem is that how can I know that which is the menu bar , img or content.As I have to do all on button click..

Answer (score 1):

The [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class will do what you want:

```
string address = "http://stackoverflow.com/";   

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string content = wc.DownloadString(address);
}
```

async version of `DownloadString` to avoid blocking:

```
string address = "http://stackoverflow.com/";

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted +=
        new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);
    wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(address));
}

// ...

void DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Error == null) && !e.Cancelled)
    {
        string content = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the yahoo page as it is in original website.But I have designed my separate aspx pages.Now I want to use images,menu bar,some content in my aspx pages.My problem is that how can I know that which is the menu bar , img or content.As I have to do all on button click..